# IdentityServer3 and Web API in same process

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have Asp.net MVC web application and webapi in same project.I am using Resource owner Credential flow to have identity management.Is it possible to configure webapi, client and identity server in same startup.cs(startup.cs of webapplication).While trying to configure webapi and identity server in same startup.cs i ended up with the following error ***"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44303/.well-known/openid-configuration'."***

Here is the code of my startup.cs:

```
using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Services;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default;
using MarilynIdentityServer.IdentityServer;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
//using System.IdentityModel.Claims;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MarilynIdentityServer.Startup))]
namespace MarilynIdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());   

            var userService = new UserLoginService();

            factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);
            factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService { AllowAll = true });

            var option = new IdentityServerOptions
            {


                SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                Factory = factory,

                //AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                //{
                //    //EnableLocalLogin = false,
                //    IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
                //},


            };
            app.UseIdentityServer(option);


            app.Map("/api", idsrvApi =>
            {
                // token validation
                idsrvApi.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Authority = "https://localhost:44303/",
                    RequiredScopes = new[] { "sampleApi" }
                });

                // add app local claims per request
                idsrvApi.UseClaimsTransformation(incoming =>
                {
                    // either add claims to incoming, or create new principal
                    var appPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(incoming);
                    incoming.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("appSpecific", "some_value"));

                    return Task.FromResult(appPrincipal);
                });

                // web api configuration
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                idsrvApi.UseWebApi(config);
            });
        }

        X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
        {  

            return new X509Certificate2(
                string.Format(@"{0}bin\identityServer\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");


        }
    }
}
```

To conclude Is it possible to configure WebApi, Webapplication and Identity Server in same application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Amit

Comment: In Amit's code, (1) I'd recommend eliminating the CORS code, as there's no need for CORS since both the API and the IdentityServer are running on the same server.  (2) I'd recommend commenting out the claims transformation code, since that code's not needed to track down the source of the exception.   Finally, (3) I'd recommend taking care to make sure that app.Map("/api" ... is not conflicting with config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(), as both of these are playing a role in setting up routing for the Web API code.  Generally, I recommend a simpler starting approach than Amit attempted here.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is possible, however I have experienced similar issues to yourself in not being able to find the local Identity Server.

What usually solves it is modifying your pipeline to have Identity Server in it's own `app.Map` block instead of the root. This seems to make it discoverable by the authentication middleware.

If you try this, don't forget to update the authority in you authentication middleware.

Comment: Is it possible to use `UseIdentityServerAuthentication` and then `UseClaimsTransformation`? because I've tried that, and the method provided as argument for the `UseClaimsTransformation` method is not called nor upon a successful authentication with provided claims, is this the right method to port aspnetcore's `IdentityUser`'s fields to `JwtClaimTypes` claims?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the goal stated by this question using a combination of [Scott Brady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3274800/scott-brady)'s [post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1) and Andras Nemes's [post](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/07/02/building-a-web-api-2-project-from-scratch-using-owinkatana-net-part-1/), both excellent.  Here's the Startup.cs that worked for me:

```
using IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace idsvr3owin
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // kick the Web API piece of this app
            app.Map(
                "/api",
                apiApp => {
                    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
                    // api.App_Start is a namespace in my app
                    api.App_Start.WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
                    apiApp.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
                }
            );
            // kick the IdentityServer3 piece of this app
            app.Map(
                "/identity",
                identityApp =>
                {
                    identityApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                    {
                        SiteName = "Standalone Identity Server",
                        // idsvr3 is a namespace in my app
                        SigningCertificate = idsvr3.Cert.LoadCertificate(),
                        Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                .UseInMemoryClients(idsvr3.Clients.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryScopes(idsvr3.Scopes.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryUsers(idsvr3.Users.Get()),
                        RequireSsl = true
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```